# Not able to click second checkbox using relative locator

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, checkbox

I have following HTML code

```
<div class="compatible-product ng-star-inserted">
  <adapt-checkbox2 class="checkbox ng-valid ng-star-inserted ng-dirty ng-touched" ng-reflect-model="false">
    <label class="checkbox__label" for= "adapt-checkbox-453-input">              
      <input class="checkbox__input" type="checkbox" id="adapt-checkbox-453-input" tabindex="0" aria-label="" aria-checked="false">
      <span class="checkbox__item"> 
         <span class="sr-only" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]"></span>             
      </span>
    </label>
  </adapt-checkbox2>
  <span class="compatible-product-name" style="">Product - ABC</span>
</div>
<div class="compatible-product ng-star-inserted">
  <adapt-checkbox2 class="checkbox ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid ng-star-inserted">
    <label class="checkbox__label" for="adapt-checkbox-454-input">           
      <input class="checkbox__input" type="checkbox" id="adapt-checkbox-454-input" tabindex="0" aria-label="" aria-checked="false">
      <span class="checkbox__item">
        <span class="sr-only" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]"></span>              
      </span>
    </label>
  </adapt-checkbox2>
  <span class="compatible-product-name" style="">Product - XYZ</span>
</div>
```

[Please check screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iOkd.png)

From which 
1) First I need to select/click on "adapt-checkbox2" who is left to Span "Product - ABC"
So I have written code as follows

```
WebElement selectCompatibleProduct1 = driver.findElement(RelativeLocator.withTagName("adapt-checkbox2").toLeftOf(By.xpath("//*[text()='Product - ABC']")));
    selectCompatibleProduct1.click();
```

**Which is working fine. Its selecting the correct check-box.**

2) But Whenever I tried to select 2nd check-box its not working. Its again clicking/selecting 1st checkbox. 
Code for 2nd checkbox is:-

```
WebElement selectCompatibleProduct2 = driver.findElement(RelativeLocator.withTagName("adapt-checkbox2").toLeftOf(By.xpath("//*[text()='Product - XYZ']")));
selectCompatibleProduct2.click();
```

Selenium Version is:- 4.0.0-alpha-3
Please can someone help me on this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are open to remove the usage of `withTagName()` and `toLeftOf()` and use core xpath updating the HTML with some of more outerHTML, answering would be much more easier.

Answer (score 0):

The first `<adapt-checkbox2>` is considered left to the element with text `'Product - XYZ'`. Sinct it's the first in the Dom hierarchy it's being returned. You can add 
`.below()` to give more precise location

```
WebElement selectCompatibleProduct2 = driver.findElement(
                                      RelativeLocator.withTagName("adapt-checkbox2")
                                      .toLeftOf(By.xpath("//*[text()='Product - XYZ']"))
                                      .below(By.xpath("//adapt-checkbox2/following-sibling::span[text()='Product - ABC']")));
```

In this case it will be simpler to just use `xpath`

```
WebElement selectCompatibleProduct2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//adapt-checkbox2[./following-sibling::span[text()='Product - XYZ']]"));
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have tried both ways mentioned above by you. but still facing same issue.

Comment: Thank you so much @Guy. Its working fine with both solutions. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use this css selector

**Product - ABC** locator
   label>input#adapt-checkbox-453-input

**Product - XYZ** Css locator below
    label>input#adapt-checkbox-454-input

Answer (score 0):

Product - ABC : 
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='compatible-product-name']")[1]

Product - XYZ : 
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='compatible-product-name']")[2]